# Python invalid format

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Running Python 3.12 on Windows. Trying to import multiple .csv files and export as multiple color graphs. I want to add units of measurement and markings also, but I can't seem to get the formatting of my try: section. Every change I could think of to lines 11-13 give me SyntaxError.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_paths = ["1.csv, "2.csv","3.csv", "4.csv"]
import os

try:
    open (r"C:/Users/USER/FOLDER/CSV_FILES")
except: os.path.isfile(path)
with open(path, "r") as f:
    pass
finally IOError
    print("The file cannot be opened")

file_paths = [os.path.join(directory, filename) for filename in 
os.listdir(directory) if filename.endswith(".csv")]

colors = plt.cm.viridis(range(len(file_paths)))

for i, file_path in enumerate(file_paths):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    # Define data to plot
    x = df["column1"]
    y = df["column2"]

    # Create plot with unique color
    plt.plot(x, y, color=colors[i], label=file_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]) 
         
    plt.legend()
    plt.title("Graph from", file_path)

    # Save plot as image
    plt.savefig(f"graph_{i + 1}.png")
    plt.clf()
```

I tried something much simpler for the 'import os' section and I got permission error
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/USER/FOLDER/CSV_FILES'

```
 directory = open(r"C:/Users/USER/FOLDER/CSV_FILES")
 assert os.path.isfile(path)
 with open(path, "r") as f:
     pass
 file_paths = [os.path.join(directory, filename) for filename in os.listdir(directory) if filename.endswith(".csv")]
```

Expected a graph with multiple color for the 4 .csv files

Comment: The permission error appears to be because you're trying to open a folder. You need to open a specific file within the folder. Why are you calling `open` then not doing anything with the file object? And what is `path`?

Comment: The code example is broken. There is a missing `"` in the line where you define `file_paths`. Please edit the question if this error is not in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the double quotes after the first element of your list (1.csv), at line 3:

```py
file_paths = ["1.csv, "2.csv","3.csv", "4.csv"]
```

Notice that this element even looks different with syntax highlighting. That line should be instead:

```py
file_paths = ["1.csv", "2.csv","3.csv", "4.csv"]
```